# Testing a Java Long value in an if statement. Does 0 != 0

Tags: java, android, eclipse, long-integer

For the life of me I cannot figure out why I can’t get this method to enter the if statement.

```
protected void foo() {
    Date d = new Date();
    long now = d.getTime();

    long start;
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    start = settings.getLong(FIRST_USE_DATE, 0);
    Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), Long.toString(start));     

    if (start == 0) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putLong(FIRST_USE_DATE, now);        
    }
```

return true;
    }

Note that the log and debug mode shows that “start = 0”

I also tried

```
if (start == 0l) {
if (start == 0L) {
```

What the heck am I missing here?  Does 0 != 0?

I’m developing in Eclipse with Java for Android.  Thanks.

Edits:

@methodin - no sorry, that does not work.

@Aioobe - I have a breakpoint under the IF statement, that never gets made.

Edit2: Here is the actual code I'm running since you've asked.

```
protected boolean isDemoExpired() {
    Date d = new Date();
    long now = d.getTime();

    long demoStart;
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);   
    demoStart = settings.getLong(FIRST_USE_DATE, 0);        

if (demoStart == 0) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putLong(FIRST_USE_DATE, now);
    System.out.println(Long.toString(demoStart)); 
    return false;

}
return true;
    }
```

Comment: What about if((long)start == 0)

Comment: Have you added a debug-output within the if-branch? Are you sure it doesn't go into it?

Comment: Edited original post for your comments.

Comment: I think aioobe means put a `System.out.println("Yep, definietly in the if statement");` in your if statement.  I've seen breakpoints not be effective before.

Comment: I added it and my actual code.

Comment: Could `settings.getLong(FIRST_USE_DATE, 0);` be throwing an exception?

Comment: You're trying to verify that you entered the `if`, yet you put your `println` near the end. This is a mistake, because it's possible that you can throw before that point. Put one print immediately prior to the `if`, and one immediately after the opening brace.

Comment: And since this looks like GUI code, be aware that uncaught exceptions essentially disappear -- the method won't complete, but you may never know that the exception occurred (in the Sun JVM, they'll be written to the console, but in Android probably not).

Comment: What happens when you step through the method? i.e. break before the 'if'. I your breakpoint's on the 'return false' line it will never trigger. I stuck this bit of code into an Android app and as far as I can see, the system.outs don't go anywhere, even though the 'if' block is entered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is exactly the opposite.
I've just debugged your code and it works, the problem is that the if statement it's always true because there's no editor.commit() after making the changes to the FIRST_USE_DATE variable.

```
protected void foo() {
    Date d = new Date();
    long now = d.getTime();

    long start;
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    start = settings.getLong(FIRST_USE_DATE, 0);
    Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), Long.toString(start));     

    if (start == 0) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putLong(FIRST_USE_DATE, now);
        ***editor.commit();***       
    }
}
```

Edit: I've just tried debugging your actual code and the same thing happened: the if statement it's always true and it gets made every time because there's no editor.commit() to save the changes to the FIRST_USE_DATE variable.

```
    protected boolean isDemoExpired() {
    Date d = new Date();
    long now = d.getTime();

    long demoStart;
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);   
    demoStart = settings.getLong(FIRST_USE_DATE, 0);        

    if (demoStart == 0) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putLong(FIRST_USE_DATE, now);
        ****editor.commit();****
        System.out.println(Long.toString(demoStart)); 
        return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You are correct, and that did solve the problem.  Now I'm baffled as to why the hell my breakpoints are not working correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use Long start instead of long and check for null value?

```
protected void foo() {
    Date d = new Date();
    long now = d.getTime();

    Long start;
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    start = settings.getLong(FIRST_USE_DATE, 0);
    Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), Long.toString(start));     

    if (start == null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putLong(FIRST_USE_DATE, now);        
    }
}
```

it seems that auto-unboxing is happening here and you get zero value. Another question is why 0 == 0 check doesn't pass.

Comment: Long with a capital 'L' can certainly be null, but will fail when unboxed.  You will need to update your conditional logic with this: "start == null || start == 0"

Comment: Ok, I see.  Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake somewhere...

Are you sure you are not entering the if statement AND that start = 0 ?

Are you showing us the code you are running ?

You could execute following code (equivalent to your code)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = 0;
    if (start == 0) {
        System.out.println(Long.toString(start));
    }
}
```

And you'd see you enter the if statement...

Comment: Yea I tried that and it worked earlier.  That's why I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the concepts of hiding and shadowing?  Do you have any other variables using the same names in this class or one of its parents?

I don't think there is anything wrong with your code - try rebooting your computer (its a Microsoft OS right? :)

If that don't work delete the offending code (end up with an empty method) compile and test to ensure there are no bugs.  Then hardcode an acceptable value and test again.  Finally retype your code - do not paste a copy.

Once, a very long time ago, I had something similar and it did not go away until I re-entered the code - my best guess is some hidden character was causing problems, but I have never seen it again (nor am I certain what the hell happened that time either).